# nodejs - how to fix the server script to avoid being getting crashed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, centos7

Can anyone please check this server script i am running in CentOS 7, its crashing every day, i cant figure out what is causing it to crash?

When i am trying its not crashing but while running in server suddenly it crash and i have to manually execute it again.

Where i should apply `try { } catch {}` to avoid this to get crash at-least?

```
var db = [];
var ordered_arr = {};

var database = '-mydb';
var database_host = 'www.remote.com';
var database_user = ‘username’;
var database_pass = ‘pass’;

var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var url = require('url');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);
var mysql      = require('mysql');
io.set('log level', 1);

function add_to_global(input) {
  for(var key in db) {
    if(db[key][0]===input[0]) {
      db[key] = input;
      return;
    }
  }
  db[db.length] = input;
}

function groupit() {
  ordered_arr = {};

  for(var i=0;i<db.length;i++) {
   if(ordered_arr[db[i][2]]) {
      ordered_arr[db[i][2]]+=1;
    } else {
     if(db[i][0] !="") {
      ordered_arr[db[i][2]]=1;
     }  else {
       ordered_arr[db[i][2]]=0;
     }
   }
  }  
}

function edit(input, upgrade) {
  for(var key in db) {
    if(db[key][0]===input[0]) {
      db[key] = upgrade;
    }
  }
}

function del(input) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < db.length; i += 1) {
        if (db[i][0] === input) {
            db.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
}

function get(input, url) {
  input = input.replace("-agent", "");
  input = input.replace("-kiosk" , ""); 
  input = input.replace("-_kiosk", "");
  input = input.replace("-", "");

  console.log('>>> After modified: ' + input);
  var options = {
    hostname: url,
    port: 80,
    path: '/ajax/browserclose?username=' + input + '&status=offline&url=' + url,     method: 'GET'
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });
  req.end();  
}

var db_connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : database_host,
  user     : database_user,
  password : database_pass,
  database : database
});

db_connection.connect(function(err) {
  console.log(">>> MySQL DB connected!");
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.resources = {
    channel:'',
    username: '',    
    message:'',
    verify:'',
    status: '',
    url:’url.url.com',
    preview:'',
    viewer: '',
    database: ‘mydb’,
    destination: ''
  }; 

  function add_to_child(input) {
    socket.resources.channel = input.channel;
    socket.resources.username = input.username;
    socket.resources.message = input.message;
    socket.resources.verify = input.verify;
    socket.resources.status = input.status;
    socket.resources.url = input.url;
    socket.resources.preview = input.preview;
    socket.resources.viewer = input.viewer;
    socket.resources.database = input.database;
    socket.resources.destination = input.destination;
  }

  socket.on('joinChannel', function (from, msg) {
    console.log('>>> Received: ', from);    
    var input = from.username.replace("-agent", "");
    input = input.replace("-kiosk" , "");  
    input = input.replace(“-_k”, "");
    input = input.replace("-", "");

    add_to_child(from);

    add_to_global([ socket.resources.username, 
                    socket.resources.status, 
                    socket.resources.channel,
                    socket.resources.message,
                    socket.resources.verify,
                    socket.resources.url,
                    socket.resources.preview,
                    socket.resources.viewer,
                    socket.resources.database,
                    socket.resources.destination
                  ]);

    groupit();

    var sql = "SELECT *from tble where username='" + input + "' limit 1";
    var db_return;
    db_connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('>>> MySQL: ' , rows);
      db_return = rows;  

      try {
        io.sockets.emit('message', {
          channel: from.channel, 
          username: from.username,
          message: from.message,
          verify: from.verify,
          status: db_return[0].status,
          url: from.url,
          preview:from.preview,
          viewer:from.viewer,
          database: from.database,
          destination: from.destination, 
          group: ordered_arr
        });
      } catch(eee) {

        io.sockets.emit('message', {
          channel: from.channel, 
          username: from.username,
          message: from.message,
          verify: from.verify,
          //status: db_return[0].status,
          url: from.url,
          preview:from.preview,
          viewer:from.viewer,
          database: from.database,
          destination: from.destination, 
          group: ordered_arr
        });

        console.log(eee);
      }    
    });

    console.log('>>> Connected: ', JSON.stringify(db), sql);
  });

  socket.on('query', function(from) {
    console.log('>>> Query: ', from.username);    
    for(var key in db) {
      if(db[key][0]===from.username) {          
        io.sockets.emit('result', {
          username: db[key][0], 
          preview: db[key][6]
        });

        return;
      }
    }

  });

  socket.on('sQuery', function (from, msg) {
    console.log('>>> sQuery Received: ', from);    
    var input = from.username.replace("-agent", "");
    input = input.replace("-kiosk" , "");  
    input = input.replace("-_kiosk", "");
    input = input.replace("-", "");

    add_to_child(from);
    add_to_global([ socket.resources.username, 
                    socket.resources.status, 
                    socket.resources.channel,
                    socket.resources.message,
                    socket.resources.verify,
                    socket.resources.url,
                    socket.resources.preview,
                    socket.resources.viewer,
                    socket.resources.database,
                    socket.resources.destination                    
                  ]);
    groupit();

    try {
      io.sockets.emit('message', {
        channel: from.channel, 
        username: from.username,
        message: from.message,
        verify: from.verify,
        //status: db_return[0].status,
        url: from.url,
        preview:from.preview,
        viewer:from.viewer,
        database: from.database,
        destination: from.destination,
        result: db, 
        group: ordered_arr
      });

    }catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('>>> Connected: ', JSON.stringify(db));
  }); 

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('>>> Browser closed by: ' + socket.resources.username);
    del(socket.resources.username);
    console.log('>>> Disconnected: ' + JSON.stringify(db));
    get(socket.resources.username, socket.resources.url);
    groupit();
    io.sockets.emit('sresult', {
      result: db, 
      group: ordered_arr
    }); 

  });
});
```

Comment: do you have a log in your server? you should only use try and catch for parsing JSON

Comment: To automatically restart after crashes, you can use a process manager like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) – but don’t just ignore the errors. Fix them!

Comment: Need error logs. For more info on error handling in NodeJS try this. https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Comment: @minitech: I found the solution here: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/680  , forever does not work looks like it has itself BUG cause it crash itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message)
  console.error(err.stack)
})
```

Since nodejs is a single process server, you can place this code anywhere in js script for this to act as a catch all for unhandled/unforeseen errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use domains in order to catch an uncaught exception in Nodejs.

A sample code for catching exceptions using domains is as below:

```
function onError(req, res, next) {
    var reqdomain = domain.create();
    domain.active = reqdomain;
    reqdomain.add(req);
    reqdomain.add(res);
    reqdomain.on('error', function(error) {
        //Log your error here.
        next(error);

    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        reqdomain.dispose();
    });
    reqdomain.run(next);
}
```

Register this function in express using:

```
app.use(onError);
```

More on Domains (from Nodejs docs): [Link](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html)

[Blog on many uncaught exception scenarios handled](http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/)